# Communicating two or more browser tabs, which could be the best method?

Tags: javascript, php, tabs, websocket, ide

I want to design a small (at least, the very basics for now) IDE to make websites and applications with HTML, CSS, Javascript and a full LAMP stack.

One of the things I would like to do is to be able to open the preview window in a different browser tab (instead of having it in an HTML-encoded tab (a `<div>` element or similar), like Dreamweaver does) or even, while in source mode, being able to display the toolset in another browser tab and displace this tab onto a second display (or even a third one, although I have just one display, but it's for illustrating my situation).

Once deployed in another browser tab, I want for every browser tab to reflect any changes done to any of the other browser tabs.

For example, if I have the source view in one display and open the properties grid in another and I change a color input value, I want the output view to reflect this change in color for whichever component gets the update.

I have my mind quite clear on how to approach the data structures, how to do the preview, data caching, storing the project data, etc.

What I don't have that clear is how to effectively communicate the tabs between them. One idea is to use a combination of AJAX requests and server-sent events (SSEs) to communicate but, even if that could work, looks like crude to me.

I was thinking on something like websockets with message passing. I could encode any changes in a given component, send them to the server and have it route to the appropiate listeners for each one of them to reflect any change locally.

I have very litte experience with websockets, though... so I'm in doubt. Can you give me a hint on what could be the most efficient method here?

Answer (score 1):

I've experimented recently with WebSockets, in combination Java on Server and JavaScript on client side. First wanted to go with simple Java SE, had a nightmare, didn't succeed to make it work and at end the found this tutorial:

https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websockets-an-introduction/

Works like charm. Just stick with environment mentioned there - Java EE, GlassFish, NetBeans... Not saying that NetBeans is best IDE or something...

Of course, there is NodeJS option for back-end if you preffer JavaScript.
But generally speaking WebSockets works...and works well. :)